# Listen to mouse and keyboard events using python

Tags: python-3.x, pynput

**i am trying to prompt error massage if the keyboard or mouse is not in used for some chunk of time. for that i tried pynput module, which is not worth for me. can anyone help me for this thing, thank you**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code will print(xxxxx) if you don't move(or click) your mouse and press your keyboard in five seconds.

```
from pynput import mouse,keyboard
import time
def on_move(x, y):
    global LastTime
    LastTime = time.time()

def on_click(x, y, button, pressed):
    global LastTime
    LastTime = time.time()

def on_scroll(x, y, dx, dy):
    global LastTime
    LastTime = time.time()

def on_press(key):
    global LastTime
    LastTime = time.time()

LastTime = time.time()
listener = keyboard.Listener(on_press=on_press)
listener.start()
listener = mouse.Listener(on_move=on_move,on_click=on_click,on_scroll=on_scroll)
listener.start()
while True:
    if time.time()-LastTime >= 5: # the break time,5 is second
        print("You need break your computer")
        LastTime = time.time()
```

Comment: first of all thanks for your help. its work fine independent. but when i merge this code with my rest script i don't know its not working.